# Create New Serial Class Inheriting from Stream

Tags: serial, softwareserial, class, stream

How should I inherit from `Stream`, for creating a new class `MySerial` able to be initialized from a `Stream0` instance?.

The error so far is: `"cannot declare variable 'mySerial' to be of abstract type 'MySerial'"`.

If I make a class `MySerial` not inheriting, but adding a property `Stream`, everything works fine, except the new call mechanism for the `resend()` function, created to accept `Stream` instances.

EDIT: This is the edited code. Current error is: `"expected unqualified-id before '=' token"`.

*MySerial.h*

```cpp
class MySerial:public Stream{
    private:
        int param;
    public:
        MySerial(){}; // OK
        MySerial(Stream &Serial0){MySerial=&Serial0} // Here is the question
        // Stream Implementation
        int available(){return available();}
        int read(){return read();}
        int peek(){return peek();}
        size_t write(uint8_t c){return write(c);}
        using Print::write; 
};
```

*MySerial.ino*

```cpp
#include <MySerial.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial swSerial(6,7);
MySerial mySerial(swSerial);

void setup(){}
void loop(){    
    if (mySerial.available()){
        c=mySerial.read();
        resend(mySerial,c);
    }
}
// This function should accept any Stream: SoftwareSerial, MySerial, Serial...
void resend(Stream &Stream0, char c){
    Stream0.write(c);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Stream` class has pure virtual methods which must be implemented in derived not abstract class.

The pure virtual method from base class `Print` is:

```
virtual size_t write(uint8_t) = 0;
```

The pure virtual methods from `Stream` are:

```
virtual int available() = 0;
virtual int read() = 0;
virtual int peek() = 0;
```

additionally add in your class the line

```
using Print::write;
```

to pull in overloaded methods write(str) and write(buf, size) from`Print`

[Here](https://github.com/jandrassy/TelnetStream/blob/master/src/TelnetStream.h) I have an example of a simple class derived from `Stream`.

---

EDIT: Most of your question seemed to focus on wrapping some Stream implementation. Now I see that you maybe want to enhance the SoftwareSerial class and add a new method in the inherited class. It is simple:

MySerial.h

```
#ifndef _MYSERIAL_H_
#define _MYSERIAL_H_

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

class MySerial: public SoftwareSerial {
private:
  int param;

public:

  MySerial(uint8_t receivePin, uint8_t transmitPin) :
      SoftwareSerial(receivePin, transmitPin, false) {
    param = 0;
  }

  void resend(char c) {
    write(c);
  }
};
#endif
```

MySerial.ino

```
#include "MySerial.h"

MySerial mySerial(6, 7);

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    int c = mySerial.read();
    mySerial.resend(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the indicated changes. I am still troubled with the constructor declaration, for taking a Stream object as initial object.

Comment: Your answers are great just as the last time. I will study this code further.